# Are git clone receiving object and checkout the same

Tags: git, git-clone

I was going through an article which said:

> During the git clone, you'll find that checkout takes a long long
>   time.

I don't know what that meant by 'checkout'. Does it mean 'Receiving objects'? I was cloning a repo and this is the outcome on the cmd prompt:

```
git clone mygit@abc.com:dir
Cloning into 'dir'...
remote: Counting objects: 251877, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (115770/115770), done.
Receiving objects:  22% (57476/251877), 185.21 MiB | 53.00 KiB/s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git clone is a two step process (by default):

1. all git objects and refs are downloaded (I.e., the .git directory is populated; this is the receiving objects step)
2. the working tree is checked out (normally the remote HEAD)

Comment: Checking out step comes after 'receiving objects' is finished?

Answer (score 1):

`git checkout` is used to switch between branches of a repo. `git clone` also checkout the default branch (where HEAD is pointing to) as well.

`Receving Objects` basically downloads all the files (of all brnahces) and is NOT equivalent to `git checkout`.

Comment: Yeah! I am aware of this. I was asking if the author means 'receiving objects' when he says 'checkout' . I know this is too subjective, but thought of asking this anyway. Thanks for your answer though :)

Comment: My understanding is that clone downloads all the branches (which is basically the `Receiving Objects` step). It's not the checkout step though